# whats the proper syntax to fade in an element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am trying to Fade in the name of my site when the page loads using jquery But it's not working, unless I do it in the console. So I know it works but not sure what I'm doing wrong I saw the documentation and tried this

```html
{% if title == 'home' %}
    <header class="intro-header" id="hedr" style="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" style="height:500px">
                <div >
                    <div class="site-heading">
                        <h1 class="site-name text-center pic" id="heights">HiSPANIC HEiGHTS</h1>
                        <!--<hr class="small">-->
                        <!--<span class="subheading">A Clean Blog Theme by Start Bootstrap</span>-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
{% endif %}

<script>
  $(document.body).ready(function(){
    $("#heights:hidden:first" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
  });
</script>
```

I'm using Django if that means anything to my answer. Let me know what I'm doing wrong so I can fix it thanks

Comment: Id should be unique. Why are you using `:first`?

Comment: `:first` is redundant with an `id` selector (or it should be) and you should use `$(document).ready(...` not `$(document.body).ready(`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#heights" ).fadeIn(500);
});
```

Here 500 means 500 millisecond. That way 1000 millisecond is 1 second. In that way you can specify how slow or fast your fade in will work.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ indicates that `'slow'` should be an acceptable option as well

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This works

```
    <script>
      $(document.body).ready(function(){
          $("#heights").hide().fadeIn(3000);
      });
    </script>
```